# if action result is empty for partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Have action result for my partial view. 
Partial view fires on  click.

Javascript :

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result=="")
                    alert("EMPTY");
                else
                $('.comments-wrap').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

My Pager div :

```
<div id="myPager">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @*<div class="comments-wrap">*@
        <div class="comment">
            <div class="comment-head">
                <h4 class="name">Name : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h4><h5 class="date">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentText)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @*</div>*@
    }
    @*@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetComments", new { page }))*@
    <div class="avoid">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("GetComments", new { page }))
    </div>
</div>
```

Response from server :

[image: Response from server]

My controller :

```
return PartialView("GetComments", comm.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 7));
```

How to handle if comm is null???

Thank you for help in advance !

Comment: I'd recommend making sure you're passing SOMETHING over as a model - if comm is null, set it to a new empty list, then do a Model.Any() check in the view.

Comment: where are you getting comm value?

Comment: @JamieD77 comm value is a list of comments. Comments comes from database table. It works fine when is filled.